# Is there an equivelent of Win32 API MoveFileEx() in C++ filesystem?

Tags: c++, winapi, c++17, std-filesystem

I am porting a codebase that depends on Win32 API to C++ 17. There is a class that is responsible for handling files. The function I am currently looking at looks like this:

```
bool project::filesystem::FileSystem::rename(const std::string& oldFileName, const std::string& newFileName)
{
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(WIN32)
    BOOL res = ::MoveFileEx(nativePath(oldFileName, false).c_str(),
        nativePath(newFileName, false).c_str(), MOVEFILE_WRITE_THROUGH);

    return (res != FALSE);
#else
#pragma message("FileSystem::rename() not implemented on non-Windows OS.");
    return false;
#endif
}
```

where `project::filesystem::FileSystem::nativePath(...)` converts a string that contains a path to the native representation.

The compiler is **MSVC v141**, so I need to use `std::experimental::filesystem` and the full set of features might not be present. Is there an equivalent to `MoveFileEx(...)` or do I have to combine [`copy(...)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy) with [`remove_all(...)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/remove)?

Comment: Do your compiler support [std::filesystem::rename](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/rename) ?

Comment: Yes, indeed it works in terms of no errors when building.

So basically `MoveFileEx()` is like `mv` in Linux. :)

Comment: Sidenote: As far as I understand the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-movefileexa), `MOVEFILE_WRITE_THROUGH` has no effect without `MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED` (but it probably doesn't hurt either way).

Comment: `MoveFileEx` is a range of things, depending on the flags you use. You can read the documentation to find out what these things mean.

Comment: You cannot reliably represent file names in Windows using `std::string`. Regardless of that, if performance is a design goal, don't use whatever abstraction your language of choice provides when it comes to I/O. It's one of the many things that Windows' kernel does better than any of the competitors, but you're opting out of that performance benefit by programming against the least common denominator, which is ultimately POSIX.

Comment: @IInspectable "*You cannot reliably represent file names in Windows using `std::string`*" - sure you can, if you encode the string using UTF-8, and convert it to UTF-16 when calling Win32 filesystem APIs (or opt in to UTF-8 support in those APIs).

Comment: @rem How do you encode unmatched UTF16 surrogate pairs in UTF-8?

Comment: @IInspectable what do you mean? UTF-8 can encode any Unicode codepoint, even surrogate codepoints. However, unbalanced surrogates are illegal in UTF-16, you can't have a high surrogate without a matching low surrogate, they should never appear alone on their own in conforming systems.

Comment: @rem Which part of NTFS or Windows' file I/O API mandates valid UTF-16? Surely, a low surrogate by itself is a valid file name.

Comment: @IInspectable perhaps, but that should have no effect on UTF-8, as an unmatched surrogate can be encoded on its own as a standalone codepoint.  Surrogate codepoints are still codepoints, just reserved.

Comment: @rem That's not strictly possible with UTF-8. The encoding you are thinking of is WTF-8. While common for systems to not make a difference between those encodings, I'm not aware of a document that describes whether Windows' UTF-8 support is among them.

Comment: @IInspectable "*The encoding you are thinking of is WTF-8*" - actually, I wasn't, because I've never heard of it before. Interesting that someone actually put a name and a spec to it.